# Office Scripts - Loops

Tags: loops, for-loop, office-scripts, excel-online

I have a workbook that is only accessed via Excel Online, by several people. It has worksheets named after about 20 or so people (think username:  JSmith, JDoe, etc.) and on those worksheets are tables with the same names (JSmith). There are some fairly complex formulas within the tables, and for some reason we are finding that the formulas will randomly change to refer to someone else's table. Since the formulas are only supposed to refer to their own table, there really should not be any reference to someone's username in any formula (e.g. =sumif(JSmith[column name]...) vs. sumif([column name]).

I want to write a script that I'll run each day via PowerAutomate that will do a find/replace all on each sheet for each person's username. I have a list of all of the usernames on a sheet named Ref, so I would need to loop through each sheet, then loop through each username. I have a rough idea of how I would do this in VBA but I'm at a loss in Office Scripts so any help would be greatly appreciated! I can upload a sample file if needed.

I've tried doing a record to see what the code might look like but it came out extremely manual and without including the loops, which are the key piece I'm missing and unsure how to put in.

Comment: Your question requires (minimally) that you set up a reproducible example, and we would expect to see your best effort at this as well, before you ask for help. I would suggest you start with a simplified test case - a workbook with two or three tables, two or three names, and one table with a "wrong" formula. Write code to loop through the two or three names and update that formula. Although in general, it sounds like your REAL problem is "randomly changing formulas" which I can assure you Excel does not do. You may have bad user behavior or some other problem.

Comment: see [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how-to-aks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming the list of names is the only column on the sheet named "Ref."

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let refSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Ref");
    // get name list on Ref sheet
    let nameList = refSheet.getUsedRange().getValues();
    // loop through name list
    nameList.forEach( cell => {
        let personName = cell[0].toString();
        console.log(personName)
        // get the sheet named as person name
        let personSheet = workbook.getWorksheet(personName);
        if(refSheet){
            // get the table (ListObject)
            let personTab = personSheet.getTable(personName);
            if(personTab){
                // replace the formulas
                personTab.getRange().replaceAll(personName, "", { completeMatch: false, matchCase: false });
            }
        }
    }
    )
}
```